# calling a function (which requires parameters) as a parameter

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function which accepts another function as a parameter, so I can use it like

`waitFor(something)`

Where `const something = async function(){...}`

What if `something` was a function with a parameter? How would I use that with `waitFor`?

If I do `waitFor(something(id)` I get the error `the fn described in waitFor is not a function.` because `something(id)` is not a function but a function call right?

Comment: @Ivar yes, it does. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

waitFor(function(){ return something(id); });